# Everybody is asking you to vote - Economics.se is no different

Tags: discussion, site-activity, site-analysis

Here are some data from site analytics, regarding the last twelve months:
**Traffic** holds and has recently picked up strongly to historic highs:

[image]

...but **voting** exhibits a clear downward trend irrespective of traffic:

[image]

...while "Questions" also tend to slope downward :

[image]

Meanwhile, "Answers per Question" appear to have stabilized around $0.9$ :

[image]

**Tentative Descriptive Summary: people keep coming but mainly to look and search existing content, while active participation is not satisfactory**: voting falls, questions tend to fall, answers per question are not what they should be (ideally I would say it should be $2$ A's per Q, at least $1.5$ A's per Q).

**Let's vote more** - this is 2016 after all and many people are voting for something important in one country or the other. It is the aspect of site activity easiest to improve, and it has its way of helping the core Q & A function.

Comment: Ironic that nobody is up-voting your post. I am trying to do my bit...

Comment: @Ubiquitous Yes indeed!.. and don't be modest, you are just the second user to exceed 1.000 votes cast.

Comment: I'll do my best. Btw, IMO, the number of views is more important than votes in identifying the questions worth answering. People find Econ.SE in Google, and views show when a question is SEO-friendly and, therefore, required by many.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Big ole up vote on this post. Voting, or the the absence thereof, is one of the big differentiating factors between making an impersonal Q&A site and _building a community_. Good on you for encouraging the latter.